# Swift - is there a standard protocol that defines +,-,*,/ functions, which is adopted by all "arithmetic" types like Double, Float, Int etc.?

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

I want to write a generic function that will return a sum of it's two parameters, like the one below:

```
func add<T: ???>(left: T, right: T) -> T {
    return left+right
}
```

Of course, in order to use `+` operator, `T` type needs to conform to a protocol that defines `+` operator.

In case of several other operators, there are built in protocols - e.g. `Equatable` for `==`, and `Comparable` for `<`, `>` etc. Those protocols are adopted by all Swift's built in "arithmetic" types like Double, Float, Int16 etc.

Is there a standard protocol that defines `+`,`-`,`*`,`/` operators, which is adopted by ALL "arithmetic" types like Double, Float, Int, UInt, Int16 etc.?

Comment: What you're doing is exactly how to do it. It isn't clear what answer you're looking for; your question isn't really a question, more of a moan...

Comment: Why should `Double` conform to `IntegerArithmeticType`? A Double can represent something that is not an Integer.

Comment: can you please improve this question, or remove it? -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the problem of the question? He's asking if there's a better way.

Comment: Ok, I rewrote the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Ok, I understand your question from a theoretical point of view. But in practice, what is your purpose? You already have the `add` function defined for all these types, and you can invoke it using the `+` operator. So what do you really need to do?

Comment: @appzYourLife You could tell the same about `>` and `==` for example. They are available for all these types separate, but yet they are "grouped" under corresponding protocols (`Comparable` and `Equatable`). You want  a practical application? E.g. writing an aggregate `sum()` method that would work with Collection containing any of numeric types. Without such protocol you have to override such method for each type separately.

Comment: @grzegorzdvipek: Ok I see your point. Thank your for your further explanation. I think the answer by Kametrixom below could solve your problem.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't anything in the library for that, I get what you mean. You can do it yourself though:

```
protocol Arithmetic {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func -(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func /(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

extension Int8 : Arithmetic {}
extension Int16 : Arithmetic {}
extension Int32 : Arithmetic {}
extension Int64 : Arithmetic {}

extension UInt8 : Arithmetic {}
extension UInt16 : Arithmetic {}
extension UInt32 : Arithmetic {}
extension UInt64 : Arithmetic {}

extension Float80 : Arithmetic {}
extension Float : Arithmetic {}
extension Double : Arithmetic {}


func add<T: Arithmetic>(a: T, b: T) -> T {
    return a + b
}

add(3, b: 4)
```

Comment: Yeah, I already wrote the exact same thing :) But, in my opinion, this is one of those things that really should be included in the Standard Library. Especially when Apple likes to call Swift a _Protocol Oriented Programming Language_ ;)

Comment: Apple listened and there's a protocol for that: 'Numeric'. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric

Comment: @KarolyNyisztor Numeric doesn't support division